# How to copy one row from a text file at a time in a bash for loop?

Tags: bash, for-loop, text-editor

In the following bash loop:

```
for i in {0..40}; do
    *random code* X -o file_{i}.dat
```

for each file, I am trying to replace the X with a row from another file, resulting in the following output:

```
*random code* ROW1 -o file_0.dat
*random code* ROW2 -o file_1.dat
*random code* ROW3 -o file_2.dat
...et cetera
```

Do you know any way to do it?

Comment: 1. transpose 2. read line by line

Comment: how big (MBytes) is the file? if it'll fit into memory ... read the file into an integer-indexed array (`mapfile` `readarray`, `awk`), then use a randomly generated integer to replace the corresponding array entry.  you'll also need to decide if an array entry can be modified more than once

Answer (score 1):

There are many possibilities.  Here are a couple of the more plausible ones:

**Option 1**

Read the wanted rows of the other file into an array in advance, then access the elements by index in the loop.  For example:

```
declare -a my_array
mapfile -t -n 41 my_array < other_file
for i in {0..40}; do
    do_something "${my_array[$i]}" -o file_"$i".dat
done
```

**Option 2**

Read lines from the other file on-demand as you progress through the loop. For example:

```
for i in {0..40}; do
    read -r line
    do_something "$line" -o file_"$i".dat
done < other_file
```

---

You probably want to beef up either one of those with appropriate behavior for the case where the other file doesn't contain enough lines.

Answer (score 0):

It could be done like this

```
#!/bin/bash
#read file line by line to a max of 41 and store each line in an array
lc=0
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]  && [ $lc -le 40 ]; do
    array+=("$line")
    lc=$((lc+1))
done < "input.txt"

#if array is greater than 40
if [ ${#array[@]} -gt 40 ]; then
    for i in {0..40}; do        
        printf "*random code* %s -o file_$i.dat\n" "${array[$i]}"    
    done            
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

To copy one row from a text file at a time in a bash for loop, you can use the read command to read each line of the file and then use a loop to process each line.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Open the file for reading
exec 3< file.txt

# Loop through each line in the file
while read -u 3 line; do
    # Do something with the line, for example, copy it to another file
    echo "$line" >> new_file.txt
done

# Close the file
exec 3<&-
```